# Header view which fires onListItemClick but doesn't show selected drawable?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an Android `ListView` with a header view (`ListView.addHeaderView(View header, Object data, boolean isSelectable)`).

I'd like clicks on the header view to fire `onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)`, which *seems* only possible if I declare the header view as selectable when I add it to the `ListView`.

I *don't* want the header view to use the same [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) as the rest of the views in the `ListView`, but I'm not sure how to specify it separately. (aside: I do have a different visual affordance indicating the header view has been clicked.)

Worst case scenario, I use a View.onClick for the header (and set it as notSelectable) but I'd rather not add listeners if they're unnecessary.